# What is the SGX_CDECL macro?

Tags: c++, sgx

I'm trying to understand how to create my own sgx application, so I'm scrutinizing SDK samples.
I'd like to know what the usage of SGX_CDECL is?

in the sample below as well as in general

```
/* Application entry */
int SGX_CDECL main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    (void)(argc);
    (void)(argv);


    /* Initialize the enclave */
    if(initialize_enclave() < 0){
        printf("Enter a character before exit ...\n");
        getchar();
        return -1;
    }

    /* Utilize edger8r attributes */
    edger8r_array_attributes();
    edger8r_pointer_attributes();
    edger8r_type_attributes();
    edger8r_function_attributes();

    /* Utilize trusted libraries */
    ecall_libc_functions();
    ecall_libcxx_functions();
    ecall_thread_functions();

    /* Destroy the enclave */
    sgx_destroy_enclave(global_eid);

    printf("Info: SampleEnclave successfully returned.\n");

    printf("Enter a character before exit ...\n");
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Something tells me it's a compiler-independent way to use [`cdecl` calling convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#cdecl). You could check the definition of this macro and check for yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#cdecl

> cdecl, subroutine arguments are passed on the stack. Integer values and memory addresses are returned in the EAX register, floating point values in the ST0 x87 register. Registers EAX, ECX, and EDX are caller-saved, and the rest are callee-saved.

Comment: But why is it necessary to use it in this context?

Comment: Also, the macro expands to nothing. So it's not obvious why this macro would be needed in the example code. I think an answer that explains why SGX may/may not need this convention to be set for the main() function would be better than explaining what cdecl is